# C++ need clarification about destructors and scope

Tags: c++, constructor, scope, destructor

I have a problem, and I'm pretty sure I know the cause of it.  I'd just like some clarification.  I have a class that contains other classes, but I'll limit my example to two classes for simplicity.

Class A contains class B.  In class A's constructor, it initializes class B by calling B's constructor.  At the end of class A's constructor, class B's destructor gets called, which wasn't the behavior I was expecting.  Here's an example...

a.h

```
#include "b.h"

class a {
    public:
        b classB;

        a(int someParam);
};
```

a.cpp

```
#include "a.h"

//Class A's constructor
a::a(int someParam) {
    //Set class B by calling it's constructor
    classB = b(someParam);
    //Now class B's destructor gets called when exiting A's constructor...
}
```

I know that if you declare a variable without using "new", it gets destroyed when it leaves the current scope.  But I always thought that applied to the variable's scope, and not to the scope at which you assign a value to it.  That *is* the problem, right?  If it is, there's nothing wrong with doing `classB = *new b(someParam);` is there?  Or should I just use pointers instead?

Comment: Read a good C++ programming book. `classB = *new b(someParam);` is *copying* the object created by `new b` (so you have a memory leak).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line:

```
classB = b(someParam);
```

The expression `b(someParam)` creates a temporary, nameless `b` object, which is then asssigned to the member object, `classB`.  It is the destructor of this nameless temporary which is called, not the destructor of your member object.  If you want avoid the creation of this temporary, and instead directly initialize your member object with the appropriate constructor, use the initialization list:

```
a::a(int someParam)
    :classB(someParam)
{}
```

And this:

```
classB = *new b(someParam);
```

Is an instant memory leak.  You're allocating an object on the free store, copy assigning from it to `classB`, and losing the pointer.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: That was a dependent clause based on the OP's assumption about what the problem was.  The OP's assumption about the problem was incorrect.  But I'll add a note.

Comment: Okay, it makes sense now.  I was just about to switch over to using pointers, because I didn't know about the initialization list.  Thank you.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch My assumption was kind of correct, I was just looking at it the wrong way.  I was thinking about the variable classB's scope, instead of thinking about the scope of the new object I was creating.  But now it makes sense.  One of those duhhh moments haha.  But thanks for the help guys